# What kind of use cases require a 2GHz, 4GHz, 6GHz, 30GHz or 100GHz oscilloscope?

Tags: oscilloscope, clock-speed

I have been thinking of buying some oscilloscope for the work I do with Arduino. In my case it would be partly because of some usefulness and partly because it would give me a chance to learn an interesting tool.

But when I looked into the different models that are available I see that there are oscilloscopes with bandwidths of all the way to 100GHz (such as [this LabMaster](http://teledynelecroy.com/oscilloscope/oscilloscopeseries.aspx?mseries=484)).

From the information that I have found (such as [this article](http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1276244)) I can see that, as a rule of thumb, your scope's bandwidth should be at least five times higher than the fastest digital clock rate in the system under test.

As I plan on working mostly on Arduino I would probably do fine with some scope where the bandwidth is less than 1GHz.

But I am curious on what systems would have a "clock rate" that require a higher-bandwidth oscilloscope.

**Thus the question I want to ask is:**

What are examples of systems that require a 2GHz, 4GHz, 6GHz, 30GHz or 100GHz oscilloscope?

Comment: website for LeCroy shows Constellation diagram of 80 and 160 GBaud QPSK signal using two 100 GHz channels, http://teledynelecroy.com/100ghz/  VDSL carriers for R&D at Nokia Bell

Comment: G.Fast is a technology developed at Bell Labs applying advanced signal processing to the use of old copper cables allowing network providers to reach gigabit residential broadband speeds without installing new cables

Comment: Not totally relevant: the 5x oversampling has to do with *time*-domain measurements. If you are making *frequency*-domain measurements, theoretically you only need 2x due to Shannon's Sampling Theorem. In practice, you would want about 2.5x oversampling due to filter effects and phasing.

Answer (score 12):

Systems where you needed to debug, test and validate things that operate at high frequencies would require scopes with those higher bandwidths such as:

1. USB2.0
2. USB3.x
3. 6G SATA
4. PCIe Gen 3
5. PCIe Gen 4
6. 1G Ethernet
7. 10G Ethernet
8. 40G Ethernet